# How can I consistently connect to local server through network, even if changing network?

Tags: javascript, node.js, static-ip-address

### Background

I have a project whose frontend runs on Node. When I start the server locally, I get this...

```
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: http://192.168.1.183:8080/
```

but depending on the network I'm connected to, that network address can obviously change.

In order to talk to the backend, I currently use an environment variable `VUE_APP_BACKEND_SERVER='http://192.168.1.183:3000'`, but I keep having to change that variable every time the local address changes.

### What I've tried

I tried connecting to the network with a static IP, but when I run the server it still has the same address in the `App running at...` message. I can access `http://stat.IP.add.ress:8080` via the browser on the computer running the server, but running on any other devices connected to the network doesn't work (can only connect via the address in the message)

Is there a way to either...

- make that static IP accessible by other devices on the network?
  OR
- somehow access the server network address in Javascript, so that I can just connect to `${networkAddress}:3000` ?

#### Note

This is just for local dev use, I don't need a solution that will be able to capture the IP addresses of users accessing the production version.

Comment: If you're just developing locally, then you should be able to use `localhost` or the loopback address range (e.g., `127.0.0.1`). These will remain static for the same machine. If you're hosting the backend on a different machine, you might need to get a server or something that's always running and has a static IP. You can start/stop the backend but the address will remain the same

Comment: I want to access it through another device on the network, so localhost doesn't work for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do about this while you're still developing.

1. Serve the html for your Vue app from the same server that has your backend.
2. Load your Vue app javascript using a relative URL, for example  src="/path/to/vueapp.js" The browser will hit the same server.
3. When you want to run your Vue app, in development, access it by putting the URL of that server into the browser location bar.  `https://localhost:3000` is the way you access it on your local machine.

Then, when you're ready to go live, put your server code on a machine with a hostname in DNS (let's say `myvue.example.com`). Then access it with `http://myvue.example.com:3000`.

Also, somewhere along the way to release you need to figure out how to use `https`. That's too much to put in one SO answer.

tl;dr Make your html and your vue app ride on the same server, and load the vue app with a relative URL from that same server.

Comment: Does having the frontend and the backend on the same port not cause issues? Also, not sure how that solves the issue of accessing the server through another device on the network.